# Can not create new table in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

everyone,

Im currently doing my project which require to develope a website. In this website api which is written in node js, im using mysql as a database to store the information of the user. In order to determine which data belong to which user, i intended to create a new table for each registerd user to store the information of that specific user. To retrieve the specific data belong to a specific user, i will create a table corresponding with the user username. However, i can not create the table inside node js with the following code:

```
app.post('/signup', (reg, res) => {

    username = reg.body.username;
   
    const userpassword = reg.body.password;

    db.query( 
        "SELECT * FROM Authentication WHERE username = ?",
        [username],
        (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Server error' });
            } else {
                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    // Username already exists
                    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'same username' });
                } else {
                    // Username is unique, proceed with INSERT
                    db.query(
                        "INSERT INTO Authentication (username, userpassword) VALUES (?,?)",
                        [username, userpassword],
                        (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Server error' });
                            } else {
                                res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Registration successful' });
                                db.query(
                                    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ?? (TradeID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Price INT NOT NULL, Amount INT NOT NULL, Total INT NOT NULL, TradeType VARCHAR(255), TradeDate VARCHAR(255), TradeTime VARCHAR(255))'
                                ), [username] , (err, result) => { console.log(err) };
    
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    );
})
```

is there any way better to store the specific data related to a specific user like this without creating a new table?

Best regard

i tried to lookup in mysqljs github page about the creation of the table but there is no data about it.

Comment: When you run the code are you seeing any errors? What messages are you seeing on the console or the response? In general, you can create a table in MySQL database using the NodeJS driver.

Comment: _"is there any way better to store the specific data related to a specific user like this without creating a new table?"_ Yes there is a different way  and cant say if it is better or not with the available information. Also, this looks like different question than the title of the post, and is related to designing the database (or data modeling).

Comment: hi, thanks for ur comment, on my console, its doesn't log any error although im using console.log(err) below the db query statement. Sorry that im not providing the full context of the code that im working on: this is the api that i design for the trading platform, when the new user signup, initially, a new database will be created correspoding to the user's username to store the information such as what product they buy and what time they buy that product. The database created for the user to access the order history of them self